# Maven error: Not authorized, ReasonPhrase:Unauthorized

Tags: java, maven, repository, maven-3, nexus

I checked out my code from the Nexus repository repository. I changed the password for my account and set it correctly inside my `settings.xml` file. While executing `mvn install clean` I get the error saying `Not authorized, ReasonPhrase:Unauthorized` when it tries to download files from that repository.

Any idea how to solve this error? I am using Windows 7 with Maven 3.04

Comment: can you post the whole error?

Comment: Just got the same error and could not figure it out either. I am using a customized settings.xml which is the same for the whole team.
I downgraded to 3.0.3 and could not reproduce the same "easonPhrase:Unauthorized." issue.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/32119725/32453

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem here was a typo error in the password used, which was not easily identified due to the characters / letters used in the password.

Comment: what was the problem with the characters / letters? and how did you solve it?

Comment: The problem was that I had the password with a missing letter. This was because the password was having few letters which were repeating and so it got had to identify the missing letter initially..

Comment: Couldn't add an answer anymore, but my problem was I needed to add a server to my settings.xml file that I didn't have in there yet.

Comment: I resolved this error by adding the correct password to my global settings.xml. Using mvn clean install -X reveals the stack trace an that also helped.

Answer (score 38):

The issue may happen while fetching dependencies from a remote repository. In my case, the repository did not need any authentication and it has been resolved by removing the servers section in the settings.xml file:

```
<servers>
    <server>
      <id>SomeRepo</id>
      <username>SomeUN</username>
      <password>SomePW</password>
    </server>
</servers>
```

ps: I guess your target is *mvn clean install* instead of *maven install clean*

Comment: This will work even If I use a SOCKS proxy on Maven?

Comment: Note: On Windows, my settings.xml file was located in [ %USER_HOME%/.m2/settings.xml ], after adding the above, I no longer got the Unauthorized

Comment: The comment about the `clean` order saved me. After adding a dependency to the repository `mvn install` kept failing, until I realized I need to do `mvn clean install`. Thanks!

Answer (score 21):

I have recently encountered this problem. Here are the steps to resolve

1. Check the servers section in the settings.xml file.Is username and password correct?

```html
<servers>
  <server>
    <id>serverId</id>
    <username>username</username>
    <password>password</password>
  </server>
</servers>
```

2. Check the repository section in the pom.xml file.**The id of the server tag should be the same as the id of the repository tag.**

```html
<repositories>
 <repository>
   <id>serverId</id>  
   <url>http://maven.aliyun.com/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
 </repository>
</repositories>
```

3. If the repository tag is not configured in the pom.xml file, look in the settings.xml file.

```html
<profiles>
 <profile>
   <repositories>
     <repository>
      <id>serverId</id>
      <name>aliyun</name>
      <url>http://maven.aliyun.com/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
     </repository>
   </repositories>
 </profile>
</profiles>
```

Note that you should ensure that **the id of the server tag should be the same as the id of the repository tag.**

Answer (score 4):

You have an old password in the `settings.xml`. It is trying to connect to the repositories, but is not able to, since the password is not updated. Once you update and re-run the command, you should be good.

Comment: ..\Maven\apache-maven-3.5.2\conf that is the path to your settings.xml

Answer (score 1):

In my case the issue was that I was executing the mvn command with "sudo".

mvn test looks for credentials here:
/home/aurelio/.m2/settings.xml -> configured with repo credentials

sudo mvn test looks for credentials here:
/home/root/.m2/settings.xml -> no repo credentials configured.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced similar issue, but for me, my password had `!` in it and to fix that I updated my nexus password without `!` (I changed my password basically, you can also achieve this by escaping `!`, I found this issue when I tried to manually perform this operation from my jenkins node, it didn't like `!` in my password) and this has resolved my issue, I'm assuming `!` in my password string caused this issue when Jenkins tried to connect to SonaType Nexus from my jenkins node terminal. My issue could be totally unrelated to yours but I wanted to document my experience and solution here as well.

Answer (score -2):

I commented out/removed this part of the code from the pom.xml. And it worked. So dependencies got downloaded from maven central repos.

```
<repositories>
    ...
</repositories>
```

Comment: That does not seem to be quite the alternative, specially if you care about security at your workplace